# What is the origin of the story about Scent, Touch, Sound, Taste and Vision.?

Tags: identification-request, inspiration

I came across the story in a movie called *See* starring Jason Momoa. The story is about four brothers and sisters (Scent, Touch, Sound and Taste) and later on Vision came along and said he was their long-lost brother and he introduced the concept of beauty and ugliness, disrupting their peaceful existence. The siblings fell into discord until they realized that their happiness lay in their unity, disregarding the stranger's divisive words and returning to their contented lives.

I want to know the origin of this story or if there is any story with similar ideology that is likely to have inspired it.

Comment: It could just be completely original (or as original as anything can be, anyway). *See*, which is actually a TV series, is set in a world in which most people do not have the sense of sight and generally persecute those who do, so the story makes a great deal of sense in that context. I do not think it is likely to come from a real-world story, because in the real world the vast majority of people in essentially every society are sighted.

Comment: The society has some similarities to "The Country of the Blind" by H.G. Wells, but Wells' story doesn't have the sibling conflict